# Не запускает формы Visual Studio

Tags: winforms, visual-studio, c++-cli

Установлена Visual Studio 2019.
Создаю CLR - Пустой проект CLR
Далее:
Прошу не бить ногами больно. Windows Form решил изучать самостоятельно. Классы и прочее еще нигде не изучал. Нашел просто видео как сделать простейшую форму на С++ Делаю все за автором ролика точь в точь. Компилятор ошибок сначала не выдает, а когда запускаешь шлет куда подальше. Короче своей формы я так и не увидел. Ошибка С1001 Внутренняя ошибка компилятора Пробовал поменять тип проекта - ругается. Говорит WindowForm должен быть dll. OK. В сообщениях выдает типа:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual
> Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Current\Bin\Microsoft.Common.CurrentVersion.targets(2182,5):
> warning MSB3243: не удается разрешить конфликт между "System,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" и
> "System, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089". Произвольный выбор "System,
> Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089".

Думал из-за наличия в настройках Visual Studio двух Framework - 4.7 & 4.8 Один удалил 4.8, заметил что в Windows нет Framework. Не знаю может так и положено. И еще заметил, что мой класс (сформированный ясное дело автоматически) пустой:

```
public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: добавьте код конструктора
            //
        }
```

Это тоже смущает. Помогите пожалуйста. Очень хочу разобраться с такими вещами на плюсах.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема разрешилась. Следует обращать внимание на тип проекта. Это ОЧЕНЬ важно.
Если делать проект CLR .NET (Framework), а не как я... CLR .NET Core,  то все будет работать. Вчера проверено.